# How to display value in card based on drop down list selection?

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, sql-server-2014-express

My drop down list contain Category items from database, so when l select any item it should display its total  from the database to card or label. For instance the drop down list is loaded and the card displays total sum value for all category, so l want when l select a category let say Tools then it should display the total quantity for only Tools in the card. It been days l cannot seem to solve this. Kindly assist.

My requirement is to display from the database to card whenever drop down value change.

```
public decimal TodtalValue()
    {
        var query = "Select Sum(Quantity) AS Totalunit From OrderDetail Where Category = @Category ";
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        decimal total = 0;
        string value = "Category";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", value);
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows && dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                        {
                            total = dr.GetDecimal(0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Some recommended reading: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [it's evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/).

Comment: Also are you really still using 2014 if you're using SQL Server Express? Extended Support for 2014 runs out next year, and upgrading Express is *free*. There's very little reason to not be at least using a fully support version of SQL Server when using Express edition.

Comment: Your code doesn't actually fetch the selected value from the combobox? instead you hardcode some string

Comment: As @siggemannen says, do you actually want something like `public decimal TodtalValue(string categoryValue)`?

Comment: @siggemannen both the drop down list and card value is loaded at runtime before the drop down list action is manually applied. The card displays its initially total value of quantity, so the where clause filter total quantity per category item selected

Comment: @User_K47 - That's not entirely clear. Does this code you've posted work as you expect it to? Do you get an error? If so, which error? If not, what happens and it's not what you want?

Comment: @Dan Dumitru l don't get any error.  The project is loading fine, but when l select any item from the drop down list the card value does not change. For instance the drop down list is loaded and the card displays total sum value for all category, so l want when l select a category let say Tools then it should display the total quantity for only Tools in the card

Comment: Your comment didn't really address anything. Your code doesn't access any kind of dynamic values, and just selects by a hardcoded string `string value = "Category";` . There should be something like this: `string value = YOURCOMBOBOX.SelectedValue;`